# CSS layout with fixed top and bottom, variable height middle

Tags: html, css

```
+-------------------+
|    Top (fixed)    |
+-------------------+
|                   |
|                   |
|   Middle (fill)   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
|   Bottom (fixed)  |
+-------------------+
```

The **top** and **bottom** are fixed divs. They are positioned on the top and bottom of browser window. I want the **middle** part to fill the rest of the window between top and bottom divs.

If it's content is more than its height then i can use scrollbars. But its size should not exceed the window.

My CSS and HTML:

```css
html, body, #main
{
  height: 100%;
}
#content
{
  background: #F63;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
#footer
{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #abcdef;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">xyz</div>
  <div id="footer">abc</div>
</div>
```

From this, the Footer shows in the bottom but, the Content div still fills the whole window which should have been [window-footer] height.

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried so far?

Comment: have the height of the content to `height:auto;`

Comment: No that doesn't work. It sets the height of the **content** according to the contents in it. I need the **content** to fill the window.

Comment: give him a specified height and use overflow:auto

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Position the middle div using absolute positioning without specifying height. It does not get much simpler than this:

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #F63;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Use "Full page" option to view the snippet properly.

Comment: This is absolutely what i wanted :)

Comment: Only that `position: fixed` is not supported on lame browsers. Should work on IE7 or later though.

Comment: @rockdaboot it requires [`position: fixed` support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed); see if the rendering engine uses a modern version of webkit.

Comment: Um, where is the absolute positioning in your code? I don't see it in the #content div. Typo?

Answer (score 12):

If you don't know the header or footer sizes and you can use CSS3 then i would suggest to use flexbox layouting.

Example below (or check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0c0jwcb/))

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="footer">bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
.footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. See your fiddle with more content: https://jsfiddle.net/d0c0jwcb/12/ 
The footer is not fixed as described in the original question.

Comment: good point, but adding "overflow: scroll or hidden" to ".content" would solve it.

Answer (score 7):

html

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header"> Header Content</div>    
<div id="content">
    <ul><li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>           
        </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">I am Footer
</div>
```

css

```
      body { margin: 0;}
#main{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;}
#header
{
position: absolute;
height: 41px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background: blue;
}
#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow:scroll;               
}
#footer
{
      position: absolute;
      height: 41px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align:center;
      display:block;
      background: blue;
}

li{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5jf6/)

Comment: 2015-07-13: This doesn't work. The JSFiddle demo illustrates the problem by hiding the bottom arrow of the scroll-bar underneath the footer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what u want...

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ebilag/1/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}

.middle {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="top">Top</div>

    <div class="middle">Middle</div>

    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah! thats what i wanted. 1 thing is missing though scroll bar in the **middle** div. nvm i will find a way to put it myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height of the header and the footer...

then you could do this easily with the `box-sizing` property.

Like so:

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/11/)**  **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/10/)**

```
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0;
    padding: 64px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 64px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: The **middle** scrollbar is being coverd up by **top** and **bottom** divs

Comment: In your question you stated: "If it's content is more than its height then i can use scrollbars. But its size should not exceed the window" - so I understood from that - that you didn't want the whole browser window to scroll, only the content section itself.

Comment: you don't get my point. The scrollbar is being coverd up. I mean part of the scroll bar is below the **top** and **bottom** divs.

Comment: which browser are you using? What you are describing doesn't happen in Chrome.

Comment: I am using latest firefox. and It also happens in chrome.

Comment: @Ruchan I updated the fiddle, it now works in Firefox as well

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `top and bottom padding` is ok but I would suggest a different approach where the main frame is designed as `table`. This is more flexible and you can hide head or foot without changing the css.

STYLUS (CSS):

```
html,
body
  height: 100%
.container
  display: table
  height: 100%
.head,
.foot,
.content
  display: table-row
  box-sizing: border-box
.head,
.foot
  height: 70px
  background: #ff0000
.content
  overflow: auto
.scroll
  height: 100%
  overflow: auto
  box-sizing: border-box
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">...</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scroll">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">I am Header
    </div>
    <div id="content">I am the Content
    </div>
    <div id="footer">I am Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{width:100%;height:100%;}
#header
{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    background:#abcdef;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}
#content
{
    background: #F63;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
    min-height:400px;
}
#footer
{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    background:#abcdef;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dc6uq/1/)

Comment: The layout is what i wanted. But it gets wrong when the contents in **content** div gets large. The size of **content** is also increasing which should be non increasing but showing scrollbar in it.

Comment: `overflow:scroll;max-height:400px;` add this to content . see is this ok http://jsfiddle.net/dc6uq/3/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="content">
main content
</div>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,body{
  marign: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  background: orange;
}
#footer {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
#content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
  height: -ms-calc(100% - 200px);
  height; -o-calc(100% - 200px);
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #ccc;
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/mKchs).

Comment: It results same as #Pavel's

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use js/jquery to change the #content height during page load. 
This should be something like this (I haven't tested code below, so change it as you need):

```
$().ready(function(){
  var fullHeight= function(){
  var h=$(window).height()-100; //100 is a footer height
  $('#content').css('min-height',h+'px');
};

$(window).resize(fullHeight);
fullHeight();
});
```