# Three divs to span across the entire page(full length and width) with percentage height

Tags: html, css

I want to create a basic webpage with header, content and footer, with the header and footer each taking up 30% of the page(viewport) and the content 60%, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I tried this code: [CSS layout with fixed top and bottom, variable height middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141961/css-layout-with-fixed-top-and-bottom-variable-height-middle) but I couldn't use percentage height.

I already defined the height of html and body.

Comment: where's your code ? and what is displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want.check this and try it

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        
        body{
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
        
     div.maindiv{
      width: 100%;
      height: 768px;
     }
     div.header{
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      background-color: orange;
     }
    
     div.content{
      width: 100%;
      height: 60%;
      background-color: black;
     }
        div.footer{
         width: 100%;
         height: 30%;
         background-color: orange;
        }
    
    </style>
    
    <body>
     <div class="maindiv">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>
    
     </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. Thanks!