# How to align div in body to stay with specific height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am currently working on a single page application with angular-js. I have specific routes where I want to inject some new html templates.

To do this I created a container called with id #main which is located between two navbars (header and footer). In addition I have an image as background which is included in a seperate div above all other html elements in body.

 So the structure looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="navbar-override" ...> ... </div>

  <div id="main" ng-view></div>

  <div id="navbar-bottom-override" ...> ... </div>
</body>
```

My question now is: The #main div should always stay at the same height and width (full available h&w) over the whole page. I have [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8AjH.png) where I describe how the #main div should behave with the rest of the page. How can I achieve this alignment?

P.S.: This is the css of the html tag:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question ? Try this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141961/css-layout-with-fixed-top-and-bottom-variable-height-middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#main` div should natively stretch to the width of the screen (minus the 65px padding on each side coming from the `html`, although I would remove that padding and put it as margin on the `#main` since it looks like you want the header and footer to stretch full). If you want to force the height of `#main` to the screen height you should be able to set its height to `100vw` minus the heights of your header and footer. If your header and footer are each 50px height:

```
#main {
  height: calc(100vw - 100px);
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
}
```

Comment: ok basically it worked with the **100vh** because I guess it should take the height of the viewport. Thanks for that. How can I now force the included div to take the full height of the #main div?

Comment: Set the height of the included div to 100% and it should fill the height.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Just one last question: If the header and footer are positioned absolute/fixed can I leave the padding of the html or is it in any case a bad idea to add styling tags for html elements?

Comment: It's more a preference. I generally wouldn't put that on the HTML, but instead on the body or the div itself. If you position absolute and fix the size of the header/footer you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define style for your main:

```
#main{
   width: ---something-----;
   height: ---something-----;
   display:block;
}
```

Then you probably want deal with overflow content. See ,w hat it does: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

You may also use css capability of calculating the dimensions:

```
height: calc( 100% - 100px );
```

where 100px would be combined height of your header and footer, as an example.